# Laravel вывод данных из бд за год

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Нужно вывести данные за весь год помесячно, посчитав у двух столбцов общее количество, при том у столбца invoice_status посчитать только данные с "send" и "end".

```
ModelData::selectRaw('monthname(date) as month date, count(price) as price, count(invoice_status) as invoice')
 ->whereIn('invoice_status',['send', 'end'])
                            ->groupBy('month')
                            ->orderByRaw('min(date) asc')
                            ->get();
```

Выдаёт так:

```
{month: "April", price: 2, invoice: 2}
{month: "May", price: 13, invoice: 13}
```

Должно быть так:

```
{month: "April", price: 2, invoice: 1}
{month: "May", price: 13, invoice: 4}
```

Формат базы следующий:

```
id |     date      |price | invoice
 1    2022-05-30     150      send
 2    2022-04-20     250      null
 3    2022-01-20     180      null
 4    2022-02-20     80       end
```

Comment: Добавляйте create + insert + запрос, или какой-нибудь sql fiddle уже готовый. Запрос можете взять через [Debugbar for Laravel](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar)

Answer (score 0):

Сам решил, может кому будет нужно:

```
ModelData::select($columns)
->whereBetween('date',[
     Carbon::now()->subYear(0)->startOfYear(),
     Carbon::now()->subYear(0)->endOfYear()
     ]
   )
->whereIn('invoice_status',['send', 'end'])
->orderBy('date')
->get()
->groupBy(function($data) {
      return Carbon::parse($data->date)->format('F');
})
->map(function($entries) {
     return $entries->count();
})
);
```

Comment: на уровне sql можно было решить через `COUNT(CASE WHEN invoice_status IN ('send', 'end') THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS invoices_count`